# How to deploy ramdisk image on to disk less nodes using MAAS?

Tags: server, maas, disk, initramfs, boot-to-ram

I am using MAAS version 1.7.6 with ubuntu 14.04. Currently MAAS can deploy ubuntu/centos images on to the nodes by installing into local disk. I want to deploy my disk less nodes with ramdisk image. Every time when the nodes powered on, they should get the image from the MAAS server and boot, with out installing on to local disk. I noticed that when the nodes are commissioned, MAAS loads a micro kernel and gets all the hardware inventory of the node. I want some thing similar for deployment also. How to achieve this?